# Parsed HTML table with htmlagilitipack

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use the following code to get a table in a web page, the problem is always return the first record.
Where you can be the problem and how I fix it?

```
    Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
    Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = web.Load("http://colodchaco.org.ar/paginas/aranceles.php?cod_os=1")
    Dim tables As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")

    ' Iterate all rows in the first table
    Dim rows As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = tables(0).SelectNodes("//tr")
    'Console.WriteLine(tables(0).InnerHtml)

    Console.WriteLine("filas: " & rows.Count)

    For Each Row As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In rows
        Console.WriteLine(Trim(Row.SelectNodes("//td").Item(0).InnerText))
        Console.WriteLine(Trim(Row.SelectNodes("//td").Item(1).InnerText))
        Console.WriteLine(Trim(Row.SelectNodes("//td").Item(2).InnerText))
        Console.WriteLine(Trim(Row.SelectNodes("//td").Item(3).InnerText))
        Console.WriteLine(Trim(Row.SelectNodes("//td").Item(4).InnerText))
    Next
```

Output

```
01.01.00
Examen  - Diagn?stico y Plan de Tratamiento.
-
-
$120.00
01.01.00
Examen  - Diagn?stico y Plan de Tratamiento.
-
-
$120.00
01.01.00
Examen  - Diagn?stico y Plan de Tratamiento.
-
-
$120.00
01.01.00
Examen  - Diagn?stico y Plan de Tratamiento.
-
-
$120.00
01.01.00
Examen  - Diagn?stico y Plan de Tratamiento.
-
-
$120.00
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

Friends, it work at the follow

```
....
Dim rows As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = tables(0).SelectNodes("./tr")

Console.WriteLine("filas: " & rows.Count

For Each Row As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In rows
    Console.WriteLine(Trim(Row.SelectNodes("./td").Item(0).InnerText))
    ....
Next
```

Thanks for your anwers!!